# is db_column changing my mongodb field?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-models, mongoengine

i'm new here. I'm having a problem with `django` where i have `'type'` which is a reserved keyword as a column in `mongodb`. Based on answers in stackoverflow, I solved it by applying https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.db_column

My code currently looked like this

```
discountType = StringField(required=True, db_column='type')
```

However, the problem is the field `'type'` was changed to `'discountType'`. Is there a way to prevent the model from changing the field name?

Answer (score 0):

For mongo db_field is used instead.

See: http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html#field-arguments

```
discountType = StringField(required=True, db_field ='type')
```